# Which is the most up to date and modern RSS feed reader?

Tags: software-recommendation, rss

Which is the most up to date and modern RSS feed reader for my Ubuntu desktop?

Comment: This is a bit broad and it's going to be impossible to respond to your specific needs.  Could up update the question with more info?  A list of all possible feed readers is more appropriate for a [wiki](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/) than a Q&A site.

Answer (score 14):

[Google Reader](http://google.com/reader) works very well.  Of course, it's not Ubuntu-specific and runs in the cloud, but if you'd like accessing from multiple locations or tighter browser integration (e.g. for bookmarks), that's not something you can as easily get from a local application.

Comment: it is discontinued

Answer (score 13):

There are several options and recommending a single one is hard, because depends on how you like to read your feeds. Nevertheless, I would recommend that you try at least these:

**Firefox extensions:**

- [Brief](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4578/)
- [Feedly](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8538/)

**Built-in browser feature:**

- [Opera](http://www.opera.com/browser/)

**Adobe Air:**

- [ExpressoReader](http://www.arpitonline.com/blog/2010/08/02/espressoreader-v0-7-now-on-adobe-air-marketplace/)

**Standalone:**

- [Liferea](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/liferea)

**Plugin:**

- [evolution rss plugin](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/evolution-rss)

**Web App**

- [NewsBlur](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9757/which-is-the-most-up-to-date-and-modern-rss-feed-reader/9791#9791) (AWESOME)
- [Mac OS X Snow Leopard !](http://userstyles.org/styles/16900) Stylish script for Google Reader.

If you are looking for something modern, not the old traditional "panel view style", then try Expresso Reader or Feedly. They both integrate with Google Reader. Expresso requires adobe Air, but is really nice and have both magazine style view and list view. I personally don't like Feedly, but it is a really modern way of reading feeds.

I prefer the reader to be embedded in the browser as an extension (Firefox) or as a built-in feature (Opera). I'm currently using Opera, since I can read my feeds along with my e-mails and Brief is no longer working with Firefox 4.0. If you use evolution, then you might want to try the plugin for it.

**Screenshots:**

*Brief*

[image]

*Feedly*

[image]

*Opera*

[image]

*Expresso Reader*

[image]

*Liferea*

[image]

*Evolution Plugin*

[image]

Mac OS X Snow Leopard style for Google Reader

[image]

Comment: Fantastic post. Google reader is also worth looking at.

Comment: I have included a script for Google Reader, that is really nice and I was using before Opera.

Comment: The Opera RSS reader is excellent.

Comment: Google reader is my favorite

Answer (score 2):

And to complete the list…

1. [Snownews](http://kiza.kcore.de/software/snownews/)

[image]

2. [Newsbeuter](http://www.newsbeuter.org/)

[image]

Both, as you can see, text based.

Answer (score 2):

I also greatly enjoy [RSSOwl](http://www.rssowl.org/). It's modern, clean, and handles lots of feed formats. Features and screenshots are [here](http://www.rssowl.org/overview2).

Answer (score 2):

Thunderbird does a very nice job too, and it's built in!

Choose **New Account > RSS**

Thunderbird always seems a little neglected.  Too bad, because there is so much it can do.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you install [Liferea](http://packages.ubuntu.com/Liferea) [image: Install Liferea]. It's perfect for the Gnome Desktop.

Otherwise you can try [Blam](http://packages.ubuntu.com/Blam) [image: Install Blam].

Comment: +1 I have tried loads of RSS readers and Liferea is perfect for the GNOME desktop.

Answer (score 1):

[NewsBlur](http://www.newsblur.com/) is a new online reader by independent programmer [Samuel Clay](http://www.samuelclay.com/). It lets you read articles on the original site while keeping track of which one you're reading on the feed without interruption (you need to experience that to understand the difference it makes), does "intelligent" learning and filtering, can import from Google Reader and OPML, and has an overall well thought out user experience. Premium subscription costs $12 a year, and it's free software: the entire codebase is [on github](http://github.com/samuelclay/NewsBlur/), MIT licensed, so you can run it on your own computer without limitations (some basic familiarity with Django and PostgreSQL would be needed) and make modifications.

[image: NewsBlur]

Comment: This is AWESOME, but unfortunately it can't read askubuntu feeds. I get a warning about farming not being allowed on Firefox and Opera and the site is closed. I guess is a restriction imposed by askubuntu.com. I will try to make a pipe.

Comment: That's due to AskUbuntu's framebuster code; other StackExchange sites have it too. NewsBlur should normally autodetect it and fall back to the feed view, but it doesn't work on all sites yet. The developer is aware of the problem and is planning to make the "framebuster-buster" work better; contacting him with links to the problematic feeds might help with that. You can also fix it yourself and send a pull request on github.

Comment: Is suck workaround legal?

Comment: Of course, since it's simply parsing the feed in that case. It's not really a "workaround", in that it makes an effort to detect framebuster code in order to respect site owner's policy, and at the same time provide an acceptable reading experience.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't realize the fall back would result in limiting the view in the application to regular feed view. I thought it would display the page with a workaround. Now reading your comment I realized that this is pretty clear. Stupid me :)

Comment: BTW, I have included a recommendation to your answer in mine, because some people might not read all answers and I think this deserves more attention. I'm also voting for it now that I know why askubuntu is not displayed.

Comment: Ouch. It doesn't work nicely on Chrome - many of the popups appear behind the object their annotating.

Answer (score 1):

After trying the aforementioned RSS Readers, I've finally found a great one: [QuiteRSS](https://quiterss.org/).

It's fast, stable, actively developed, feature-rich (e.g. built-in filters) and seamlessly integrates into Gnome. There is even an up to date [launchpad ppa](https://launchpad.net/~quiterss/+archive/quiterss) available! Packages for other OS are to be found [here](https://quiterss.org/en/download).

Have fun trying it out!

Answer (score 1):

[Rosselo](https://rosselo.com), it's just being released. Although it's commercial project, payments are not required yet. Works fine in mobile browsers too.

Disclaimer: I'm the co-founder.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Akregator is awesome:
http://userbase.kde.org/Akregator

Answer (score 0):

[Fresh](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/air/sample_apps/b3/Fresh.zip), an Adobe Air app, is the one I use:

[image]
<sub>(source: [webresourcesdepot.com](https://webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/image/adobe-air-application-9.jpg))</sub>

Comment: @Zanna both work for me

Answer (score 0):

[Sage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sage/) is another Firefox RSS extension.