# Exporting thunderbird RSS feeds to liferea

Tags: thunderbird, rss, liferea

I use thunderbird as my primary RSS feed reader. Lately thunderbird has been very slow to load and very sluggish. I want to try out liferea. Is there any way to export my subscriptions to liferea (OPML or otherwise)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Thunderbird click **Manage Subscriptions** in the **Blog & News Feed** account main page, select **Export**, choose a folder and click **Save**.

In Liferea, click **Subscriptions >> Import Feed List**, select the opml file exported by Thunderbird, click **Import**.

[image]

Personally, I don't like Thunderbird or Liferea for feeds, because I like to read them inside the browser. I'm currently using Opera, but I have posted a few suggestions for standalone and other types of readers at [https://askubuntu.com/questions/9757/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9757/which-is-the-most-up-to-date-and-modern-rss-feed-reader/9762#9762)

You could also optimize your Thunderbird. Compact your mail folders from **File >> Compact Folders**. This should improve performance.

I don't use it and never tried to optimize it, like I do with Firefox. But since it is a Mozilla XUL application that uses sqlite, you could also try to optimize the databases with the following script. You will need sqlite3 command-line interface:

## [sqlite3](http://packages.ubuntu.com/sqlite3) [image: Install sqlite3]

```
#!/bin/bash

killall thunderbird
echo "Please wait while the databases are optimized..."
find $HOME/.thunderbird/ \( -name "*.sqlite" \) -exec sqlite3 {} "vacuum" \;
echo "Thunderbird databases optimized with success! You can close this terminal."
read
```